# Set allowed variable types for method parameters

Tags: php, variables

In some programming languages such as Java or C# it's allowed for programmer to set allowed input variable types. I use PHP and I want to do the same to avoid passing  wrong data to my methods/functions.

My code:

```
public static function generateFiles(array $data, Custom_Pager $pager)
{...}
```

Why is that allowed and I cant write like that:

```
public static function generateFiles(array $data, Custom_Pager $pager, int $limit, string $text)
{ ... }
```

Is any way to standardize first and second method declarations I presented above? If no, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can force the parameters to be of a certain type using [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php%20type%20hinting), but it apparently does not work with primitive types.

You can, however, throw an exception in the method if the parameter values does not meet your expectations.

```
if (!is_int($param))
    throw new Exception('param must be int.');
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a [weak-typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) language, so that isn't possible.

PHP5.1 introduced [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), though it has it's limitations:

> Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string.
>   Traits are not allowed either.

Comment: Not impossible, just harder than you might think - http://nikic.github.com/2012/03/06/Scalar-type-hinting-is-harder-than-you-think.html

Answer (score 0):

I made a function to force type hinting. It works something like that:

```
function getVar($var,$type) {
switch($type) { 
 case "int":
  return (int)$var;
 case "string":
  return (string)$var;
}
}
```

You can continue with all other types. Also you can make the same method to check variables for is_int, is_string, is_bool etc...

Comment: And your function will be like generateFiles(getArray($var1), getBool($var2), getInt($var3));

for getArray, for example, you can do:
if(is_array($var)) { 
return $var;
} else {
return array($var);
}